# Webpacker manifest.json reverts to old asset references after docker-compose up --build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, webpacker

I've been noticing a strange problem in my dockerised development environment, where the javascript assets result in a 404 error as the webpacker manifest.json is pointing to a pack that does not exist.

I've documented the problem which arises after a rebuild of the Docker container.

In all cases below I am referring to the hashed version of `admin.js`

Initial state with javascript assets loading as expected:

```
public/packs/manifest.json

"admin.js": "/packs/admin-xxxxxxc629.js",
```

the file ending `c629.js` is present in `public/packs`

If I now rebuild Docker containers with `docker-compose up --build`
I get the following output in the logs:

[image: webpacker docker log]

With the hash now ending `e105` and the manifest.json updated accordingly

```
public/packs/manifest.json

"admin.js": "/packs/admin-xxxxxxe105.js",
```

the file ending `e105.js` is NOT present in `public/packs` and so when I refresh the browser I get a 404 error for the admin-xxxxxxe105.js file.

---

*This section may be a red herring or may be a clue:*

I feel that my normal webpacker flow is a bit odd as changes to the original admin.js file result in webpacker compilation that updates the manifest.json but does not create the corresponding file in public/packs

This doesn't cause a problem as when I refresh the browser it triggers another compile that then refreshes manifest.json with a new hashed version and also creates the file in public/packs

I'm only left with the stranded e105.js after a docker rebuild.

---

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'
services:
  webpacker:
    build: .
    environment: 
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_PUBLIC=localhost:3035
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=localhost
    command: ./bin/webpack-dev-server --inline true
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - '3035:3035'
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports: 
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    environment: 
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - NODE_ENV=development
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - webpacker
      #- elasticsearch
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
```

and here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.7
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=1.17.3
RUN gem install bundler -v "$BUNDLER_VERSION" --no-document
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -  
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -   
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list   
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn build-essential libpq-dev postgresql-client
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
ENV RAILS_ENV docker    
ENV WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_PUBLIC localhost:3035  
ENV WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST localhost 
RUN git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
RUN git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
COPY package.json *yarn* ./
RUN bundle install
RUN yarn install
COPY . /myapp

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

and this is docker section of my webpacker.yml:

```
docker:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that versions and hashed value of the package contents in the project's package.json
  check_yarn_integrity: false

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: webpacker
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: true
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/
```

I've got no idea how my Docker container keeps holding on to this reference to `admin-xxxxxxe105.js` and would ideally like to fix my dev environment so that I don't have to force a change to admin.js everytime I rebuild a container.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I now just add a comment to admin.js and oscillate between adding and deleting it to force a re-compile. Very odd.

Comment: You're not alone. Do let us know if you find a permanent solution!

Answer (score -1):

Try this in **config/*YOUR_ENVIRONMENT*.rb**

> # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default
>   since   # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
>
> config.public_file_server.enabled = true

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to work. I made the proposed change in development.rb but I still get a not found error every time I take docker-compose down and back up.